# Does window.print() work in all versions of Safari on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, safari

I have a few questions regarding Print used in iPad Safari (`window.print()`)

1. Does the same JS method `print()` work in iPad Safari without needing any update?
2. Do we need to add the printer initially?
3. Does the iOS version matter for AirPrint?
4. In my page, I am using `window.print()` and it does not even give any popup or even any error. Nothing happens at all. I’m testing on iOS 3.2.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Given 4., it looks like the answer to 1. is “no”.

Comment: Well...that is what I had thought...but another person was able to atleast see the Print popup..Not sure which OS version he had though..

Comment: Which OS version do you have?

Comment: I've tested it on an old version 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about 1. and 2., but as for 3.:

> To use AirPrint, you need one of the following devices **running iOS 4.2 or later**

(Emphasis mine — http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356)