# window.print() does not pop up print dialog for PDF in iPAD

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I am opening a PDF file and autoprinting it which displays the print dialog box in all browsers(chrome,IE.Safari).But in iPAD it does not open the print dialog box automatically.

Does window.print() works with iPAD ??

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835625/does-window-print-work-in-all-versions-of-safari-on-ipad) question and answer, it may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need a printer app or at least AirPrint enabled on your iPad/network.
I don't think iPads come with native printing facilities bundled into the OS browser therefore the browser doesn't know what to do with a print request. Additionally I'm not sure that you'll be able to invoke a print call from the browser without some user actions.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6220

Comment: Thanks Alex.Yes print call happens after a user action.Though there are no printer App installed,it should show the print dialog pop up right?? It shows when i try to print html page,but PDF it doesnt pop up teh print dialog